# If i declare a vector as global variable, where is the vector allocated?

Tags: c++11, global-variables, stdvector

Everyone.

I know vector is dynamic allocated, so it is on heap. But i also know that global variables are neither allocated on heap nor stack. So where is the vector located anyway?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have

```
std::vector<int> my_global_vector;
```

defined in the global or namespace scope (i.e. outside any function), then the *object* is stored in the "data" segment of the program, together with all other (uninitialized) global or namespace variables.

The storage of the *object* is separate from the storage of the vector data, which is indeed allocated of the heap.

Comment: Thx very much for you reply! So if I declare such a vector as global, it will actually NOT take much memory, since it only stores the object. Is that right?

Comment: @DexterLiu A vector object typically contains only a couple of members (size, capacity and a pointer to the heap-allocated data), which is not much at all. ***But*** using global variables is really discouraged, try to write good and nice code without the use of global variables, passing the vector as arguments to the functions that needs it. Pass by reference if you don't want to copy or relinquish ownership of it.

Answer (score 1):

The vector itself will be placed in the static data section of your program. This is not the heap.

But when the vector is storing elements it will allocate a buffer for its data. This will be on the heap.

See below for a possible implementation. The vector is on the left - it does not contain any element data. Once it gets a request to store data, it will allocate a buffer for storing the elements of the vector. This buffer can dynamically grow or shrink.

```
static data             | heap
------------------------+---------------------
ptr to start    ------> | first element
size                    | second element
                        | ...
```

Comment: Thx for your reply, but I still dont quite understand, what exactly is that buffer?

Comment: @DexterLiu The buffer actually stores the vector elements. I clarified a bit.